# ggplot mixture model R

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot, mixture-model

I have a dataset with numeric values and a categorical variable. The distribution of the numeric variable differs for each category. I want to plot "density plots" for each categorical variable so that they are visually below the entire density plot.

This is similiar to components of a mixture model without calculating the mixture model (as I already know the categorical variable which splits the data).

If I take ggplot to group according to the categorical variable, each of the four densities are real densities and integrate to one.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width)) + geom_density() + geom_density(aes(x = Sepal.Width, group = Species, colour = 'Species'))
```

[image]

What I want is to have the densities of each category as a sub-density (not integrating to 1). Similiar to the following code (which I only implemented for two of the three iris species)

```
myIris <- as.data.table(iris)
# calculate density for entire dataset
dens_entire <- density(myIris[, Sepal.Width], cut = 0)
dens_e <- data.table(x = dens_entire[[1]], y = dens_entire[[2]])

# calculate density for dataset with setosa
dens_setosa <- density(myIris[Species == 'setosa', Sepal.Width], cut = 0)
dens_sa <- data.table(x = dens_setosa[[1]], y = dens_setosa[[2]])

# calculate density for dataset with versicolor
dens_versicolor <- density(myIris[Species == 'versicolor', Sepal.Width], cut = 0)
dens_v <- data.table(x = dens_versicolor[[1]], y = dens_versicolor[[2]])

# plot densities as mixture model
ggplot(dens_e, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line() + geom_line(data = dens_sa, aes(x = x, y = y/2.5, colour = 'setosa')) + 
  geom_line(data = dens_v, aes(x = x, y = y/1.65, colour = 'versicolor'))
```

resulting in

[image]

Above I hard-coded the number to reduce the y values. Is there any way to do it with ggplot? Or to calculate it?

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?  You need to change the scale though.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_density(aes(y = ..count..)) + 
  geom_density(aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = ..count.., 
               group = Species, colour = Species))
```

Another option may be

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width)) + 
   geom_density(aes(y = ..density..)) + 
   geom_density(aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = ..density../3, 
                    group = Species, colour = Species))
```

Comment: Hi, yes that looks promising. If I scale it with the number of entries of the iris dataset, i.e. nrow(iris) = 150, it looks quite good. So instead of ..count.. it is ..count../150. Can anyone verify that this is the correct way to go? In my case the number in each category is not the same, but there is one category which accounts for about 60% of the data.

Comment: Hi, I thought about it and discussed it and that's the correct answer. Thanks @Kota Mori for the quick reply. Either take y = ..count../Number_of_rows_of_entire_dataset or take y = ..density../number_of_categories